# AFNetworking response failure block is called instead of success block

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, afnetworking

AFNetworking response `failure` block is being called when I get status code 200. How can I make the `success` be called instead?

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:@"http://128.199.94.58/test/bt/client_token.php" parameters:nil
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         self.clientToken = responseObject[@"customerID"];
         NSLog(@"Client Token received.");
     }
     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         // Handle failure communicating with your server
         NSLog(@"Client Token request failed.%@",operation.responseString);
         NSLog(@"error code %ld",(long)[operation.response statusCode]);
     }];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the value of `error`. It will tell you why the connection failed. "Failure" in this context has nothing to do with the status code. Returning "404" is still a "success." Failure means you were unable to complete the operation.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out...the webservice had error in contenttype as text/html....now changed to application/json

Answer (score 2):

use `acceptableStatusCodes` as follows:

```
 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager =  [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.requestSerializer = [TimeoutAFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
NSMutableIndexSet* codes = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];
[codes addIndex: 200];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableStatusCodes = codes;

[manager GET:urlString parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {


 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {
 }];
```

Answer (score 1):

I run this code and it work find.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
[manager GET:@"http://128.199.94.58/test/bt/client_token.php" parameters:nil
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject
                                                              options:kNilOptions
                                                                error:nil];
         self.clientToken = json[@"customerID"];
         NSLog(@"Client Token received.");
     }
     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         // Handle failure communicating with your server
         NSLog(@"Client Token request failed.%@",operation.responseString);
         NSLog(@"error code %ld",(long)[operation.response statusCode]);
     }];
```

responce is:

```
json:
{
    customerID = "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";
}
```

It may be work for you.

Comment: this has been crashing the app...Thanks for the try

Answer (score 0):

If you check your error in failure block it clearly say that `invalid content type`. You need to set the content type of the manager as follows

```
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
```

Comment: True but this solution was crashing my app so made changes on server side...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
```

and in success block

```
 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
     NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:manager.responseData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
     self.clientToken = dic[@"customerID"];
     NSLog(@"Client Token received.");
 }
```

Comment: can u tell me whats the difference between yours and Inder Kumar Rathore answer??

Comment: He says AFJSONRequestSerializer and i m suggesting AFHTTPResponseSerializer. more edited to get results